# Questions about Trading View Fine Editor (Easy to ask questions)

Tags: pine-script

```
strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 1, when=(has_crossed == 1 and wt1 > wt2))
```

Usually, in this way, the purchase signal is displayed on the chart, but the problem is that it is displayed on the bar open price.

All I want is to put it on the stick close price. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Set `process_orders_on_close` to `true` in your `strategy()` call.

```
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, process_orders_on_close =true)
```